# Keycloak admin client Spring - list all users with realm roles

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

In my service class I have a function that deletes all users except those passed as param

```java
    public void deleteWhereNotIn(List<String> keep){
        List<UserRepresentation> users = keycloak
            .realm(realm)
            .users().list();
        List<String> remove = new ArrayList<>();
        for(UserRepresentation user : users){
            if (user.getRealmRoles() != null && user.getRealmRoles().stream().anyMatch(role -> role.equals("ADMIN")))
                continue;
            if (keep.stream().noneMatch(uid -> uid.equals(user.getId())))
                remove.add(user.getId());
        }
        for(String uid : remove)
            delete(uid);
    }
```

I don't see any problem with my logic, yet `users` have a length of `100` even though I have more and `user.getRealmRoles` is always `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see any problem with my logic, yet users have a length of 100
> even though I have

If you have a look at the [Admin Rest API documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) you can read

> Query max optional Maximum results size (defaults to 100)
> integer(int32)

which is basically what happens when you use `list()`.

Try to use [list(Integer firstResult, Integer maxResults)](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/admin/client/resource/UsersResource.html#list-java.lang.Integer-java.lang.Integer-) instead of list. Set `firstResult` to `0` and `-1` for the `maxResults`, respectively.

> user.getRealmRoles is always null

There seems to be a bug (already reported [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/14116)) with this endpoint.

You can use the workaround described on the [keycloak discourse group](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/realm-role-is-not-assigned-while-creating-user/2271).

So something like:

```
  keycloak.realm(realm)
        .users()
        .get(userId)
        .roles()
        .realmLevel()
        .listEffective()
```